# Unable to post message to Microsoft teams channel using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying post message to Microsoft teams channel using Graph API but bot no luck.

First I got Bearer token by making below call.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/22109ccf-0021-48af-947a-11111111111/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd; stsservicecookie=estsfd; fpc=ApGgHx8qh5hBlL_RviIqR3XYPIX9AQAAADMMeNgOAAAA' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id={client_id}' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret={client_secret}' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'code=' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=https://localhost:8080'
```

Using bearer token got in previous call to post message to teams channel.
but receiving `Unauthorized` error , I have added below permissions

Teamwork.Migrate.All (App)

```
Content-type: application/json

{
  "body": {
    "content": "Hello World"
  }
}
```

I tried using explore https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer but getting `MethodNotAllowed` error.

Is it possible to post message to MS teams channel by using Graph API ?In documentation it says we can https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check your token [here](https://jwtmspreview.azurewebsites.net/) and confirm if you see all the necessary permissions in it.

As per documentation, here is the list of permissions supported.
[image]

Please make sure, if you are using permission **'ChannelMessage.Send'** it is obtained using delegated context token as Application context token is currently not supported.

Hope this helps. Thanks!